# How do I print only 2 menu links?

Tags: 7, theming, navigation

I want to print the menu items as follows.

```
Menu1   Menu 2    Menu3     More
                            Menu4
                            Menu5
```

I am getting them as in the following screenshot.

[image]

The *More* menu should contain only *Menu 4* link. I created these menu links from the administrative pages.

[image]

I printed the menus using the following code.

```
$menutopleft = menu_navigation_links('menu-top-left-menu');                 
print_r(theme('links__menu-top-left-menu', array('links' => $menutopleft)));
```

Comment: Drag the Menu4 and put under the Our restaurants. Try this
and remove your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this from admin panel. Create hierarchical menu for this. See the screenshots

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: - I had already tried the option provided by you but still i am not getting the dropdown like displaying in your screenshot.Can you please provide me some code used for dropdown or any module name used to show as dropdown .

Comment: Expand the parent menu which you want to create hierarchical and add all other menu under this parent menu.( enable show as expanded checkbox. )

Comment: :Hi,i did all the changes mentioned above but still i am not getting the child menu links.Can you please provide the code to render child menu links?

Comment: this is done by the admin panel not from code.
please send me the screenshot ,which steps you follow for creating the menu.

Comment: -I had joined recently  to this community so site is not allowing me  to upload more than 2 screenshots to this question .i am unable to send you screenshots.but i followed the same process as you did in your screenshots. For rendering the menu links i had used the  code that i mentioned in my question .is it true?